# Nested array_to_json output from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have written a PSQL statement that returns multiple tables worth of data in JSON and the output is almost right, however I need to go one level deeper and I'm not sure how to do that.

The statement is as follows:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t))
from (
      select sensors.name,
      (
      select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
      from (
        select *
        from events
        where sensors.sensorid=events.sensorid
      ) d
    ) as signatures
  from sensors
) t
```

Which outputs the following:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Boston",
      "signatures":[  
         {  
            "eventid":1,
            "sensorid":1,
            "signature":223123,
            "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
            "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
            "srcport":10000,
            "dstport":80,
            "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
            "gid":null
         },
         {  
            "eventid":2,
            "sensorid":1,
            "signature":142142,
            "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
            "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
            "srcport":10000,
            "dstport":80,
            "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
            "gid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"Greenwich",
      "signatures":[  
         {  
            "eventid":12,
            "sensorid":2,
            "signature":123123,
            "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
            "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
            "srcport":10000,
            "dstport":80,
            "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
            "gid":null
         },
         {  
            "eventid":13,
            "sensorid":2,
            "signature":524123,
            "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
            "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
            "srcport":10000,
            "dstport":80,
            "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
            "gid":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Which is a good start, but what I would also like is to further layer the output so that the individual signatures become an array with all of the firings within that, so the output should be something like this:

```
   {  
      "name":"Boston",
      "signatures":[  
         {  
            "signature": 223123,
            "firings":[
               {
                  "eventid":1,
                  "sensorid":1,
                  "signature":223123,
                  "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
                  "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
                  "srcport":10000,
                  "dstport":80,
                  "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
                  "gid":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "signature": 142142,
            "firings":[
               {
                  "eventid":1,
                  "sensorid":1,
                  "signature":142142,
                  "srcip":"10.0.0.1",
                  "dstip":"10.0.0.2",
                  "srcport":10000,
                  "dstport":80,
                  "timestamp":"2016-12-10T07:00:00",
                  "gid":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
```

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t))
from (
      select sensors.name,
      (
      select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
      from (
        select distinct events.signature as signatureid,
        (
        select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(e)))
        from (
          select * 
          from events
          where  events.signature = signatureid
        ) e
        ) as firings
        from events
        where sensors.sensorid=events.sensorid
      ) d
    ) as signatures
  from sensors
) t
```

But postgres doesn't seem to like this saying "Perhaps you meant to reference the column "events.signature" or the column "events.signature"."

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select json_agg(sensor) 
from (
    select
        json_build_object('name', name, 'signatures', json_agg(signature)) sensor
    from sensors
    join (
        select 
            sensorid,
            json_build_object('signature', signature, 'firings:', json_agg(event)) signature
        from events e, 
        lateral row_to_json(e) event
        group by sensorid, signature
        ) s using(sensorid)
    group by sensorid
    ) s;
```

Comment: Hey this is looking great, it doesn't quite work though when you add more data, it's not putting each event into the array, it's building a new object each time: http://rextester.com/NCZ7287

Comment: It's a matter of inner grouping criteria. See the modified answer and [this example](http://rextester.com/INABH8185).